# Binding command on button doesn't work wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to create simple add entity to database form, but binding command doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Here is XAML

```
<DockPanel Margin="30">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Label>Manufacturer</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Manufacturer, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Label>Type</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Type, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Label>Serial number</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SerialNumber, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding AddScaleCommand}">Add Scale</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Scales}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"></ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

And here is ScaleViewModel where the command is located

```
public class ScaleViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public ScaleViewModel()
    {
        Scales = new ObservableCollection<Scale>();
    }

    public ICollection<Scale> Scales { get; private set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SerialNumber);
        }
    }

    public ActionCommand AddScaleCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new ActionCommand(p => AddScale(Manufacturer, Type, SerialNumber), 
                                    p => IsValid);
        }
    }

    private void AddScale(string manufacturer, string type, string serialNumber)
    {
        using (var api = new BusinessContext())
        {
            var scale = new Scale
            {
                Manifacturer = manufacturer,
                Type = type,
                SerialNumber = serialNumber
            };
            try
            {
                api.AddNewScale(scale);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO kasnije
                return;
            }

            Scales.Add(scale);
        };
    }
}
```

Scale is simple class with 3 properties (Manufacturer, type and serial number), and ViewModel class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo and implemented necessary methods. ActionCommand class implements ICommand and implements ICommand methods.

UPDATE added ActionCommand class

```
public class ActionCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<Object> action;
    private readonly Predicate<Object> predicate;

    public ActionCommand(Action<Object> action) : this(action, null)
    {

    }

    public ActionCommand(Action<Object> action, Predicate<Object> predicate)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Action", "Yout must specify an Action<T>");
        }

        this.action = action;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (predicate == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return predicate(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Execute(null);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors 40 in the output window? Also Labels are an overkill when you could use `TextBlock`. This also looks very WinForms to me, why would you have a `StackPanel` inside of the `DockPanel`?

Comment: No errors, just 1 warning about ex (not used)... Front end is not currently in focus, I'll later fix that

Comment: Two things irritate me: you never invoke OnPropertyChanged, and you create a new AddScaleCommand every time the getter is called.

Comment: @StephanStamm it's not the best construct, but not the cause of this issue ... the AddScaleCommand getter will only be called once.

Comment: You should raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event of your command on updating the `SerialNumber` property. Currently, your command will be always disabled.

Comment: @dymanoid My button isn't disabled because it is not even bound. Binding does not work. When I click the button, nothing happens, and of course, automatic disable of button isn't working

Comment: If you read my comment carefully, you'll note that I mean your **command**, not your **button**. This isn't an answer, it's just an observation.

Comment: Look in the output window then, or use a tool such as WPF Snoop https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf to check for binding errors.

Comment: Added ActionCommand class

Comment: Could the problem be because the command expects three parameters, but the binding doesn't specify any?

Comment: Did you set the DataContext property to your ViewModel instance in your View (xaml.cs) class? Any another binding of controls is working?

Comment: @PéterHidvégi That was the problem! Figured it out 5 minutes ago.

Comment: @TatjanaCerovic Okay, Good luck & Have fun to your project. :)

Comment: @PéterHidvégi Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I didn't add DataContext to MainWindow in App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var window = new MainWindow
        {
            DataContext = new ScaleViewModel()
        };

        window.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably have spotted this in a few minutes if you'd tried to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel class needs to implement both [IDataErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) and INotifyPropertyChanged for the validation to work.

Also, there doesn't appear any way for the ActionCommand to re-evaluate IsValid() after SerialNumber has changed.

For more detail on data validation in WPF / MVVM using IDataErrorInfo, check out my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-validation/).

Comment: I already said that ViewModel implements both interfaces. Still button doesn't trigger anything.

Comment: Please post a minimal complete and verifiable example then - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve